# extract from a file some data to have a specific process to them (in a batch)

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I need to extract some data from a file to apply them a specific process. The file structure looks like this

```
      some title information at file header

      I001=send login information to the system
       connection is OK            
      A001=System has answered: "you are connected"


      I002=press the log out button
      A002=system has answered: "You have been disconnected"
      disconnection is OK

      I003= timeout is 10
      If timeout occurs, refresh view and then check if connection is come again 
      Else retry refreshment until you are connected to the system
```

My goal is to get I001,I002,I003,... to hold only on a line. 
To do that, I write

```
    more +1 %1 | findstr /v /r "^A...=.*"
```

But I get

```
       I001=send login information to the system
       connection is OK
       I002=press the log out button
       I003= timeout is 10
       If timeout occurs, refresh view and then check if connection is come again. 
       Else retry refreshment until you are connected to the system
```

instead of

```
      I001=send login information to the system
      I002=press the log out button     
      I003= timeout is 10
```

On the other hand, Please Let me know how could I pass right away this result through a pipe to a vbs script which uses a file as parameter. When I use

```
         findstr "I[0-9][0-9][0-9]" "%~1"|cscript myscript.vbs,
```

I get an error at line fsoObj.opentextfile(wscript.arguments(0),1).readall, with fsoObj=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject").

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: For the VBS issue, create a file with the information first and use that in your VBS file.  OR read STDIN in the VBS script.

Answer (score 1):

if you search for `I` +  three numbers, simply use:

```
findstr "I[0-9][0-9][0-9]" "%~1"
```

.. no matter, what is before of after the expression, and `more` is also not needed.

Comment: Thank you, it's OK! Please Let me also know how could I pass right away this result through a pipe to a vbs script which uses a file as parameter. When I use findstr "I[0-9][0-9][0-9]" "%~1"|script myscript.vbs, I get an error at the line fsoObj.opentextfile(wscript.arguments(0),1).readall, with  fsoObj=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject"). Thankd

Comment: Sorry, but VBS is not my department.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand you correctly, but if you just want the lines starting with `I...=`, then you could just do this:

```
type %1 | findstr /r "I...=.*"
```

Given your input, this would print...

```
      I001=send login information to the system
      I002=press the log out button
      I003= timeout is 10
```

...which *I think* is what you want.

Comment: With that, I only get others line following equality with I. Indeed, if a line that begin with an 'I=' outflank the line, I ignore others lines for just keeping that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the `/v` option, it does exactly the opposite of what you want.

> /V   Print only lines that do NOT contain a match.

You're also looking for `A` at the beginning, but you want `I`, so change it to

```
more +1 %1 | findstr /r "^I...=.*"
```

Note: Your file text above is indented by 6 spaces. In that case use

```
more +1 %1 | findstr /r "I...=.*"
```

(without the `^`, because it will only match lines that *begin* with an `I`, with no spaces before.)

Comment: Sorry, It does not solve the issue. Within this file, It may be one or more spaces after any line that begin with an I. I put ^ because there is no spaces before any I. Moreover I use /V because it may be some others items like 'I' that I want to ignore, therefore I prefer printing only lines that do not contain a pattern. Thanks gain

Comment: When the lines in the file have no spaces at the beginning and I use `findstr /r "^I...=.*"`, I get *exactly* the three lines you're looking for according to the expected output you gave in your answer. Note that the pattern will not match any other lines beginning with `I` that are not exactly in the format the regular expression specifies.